# how to make calculations within loop in html table (django)

Tags: html, django

i have table in html:

```
ab=[24,56,78]
 <table >
              <tr><th>ab</th>
                {% for d in ab %}
                    <td>{{ d }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
              </tr>
          </table>
```

I know `{{d|add:100}}` but it is addition how can i do multiplication. I need the numbers to be in percent

`ab` is a list. How i can  multiply list ab by 100 within loop in html table ? and is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use widthratio builtin filter for multiplication and division aswell.

To calculate A*B: {% widthratio A 1 B %}

To calculate A/B: {% widthratio A B 1 %}

*Notice: For irrational numbers, the result will round to integer.*

Comment: so i write  {% widthratio d*100 %} ? like that ?

Comment: Yes. But dont use  *  ! You have to use 1. When you use a star you will get a TemplateSyntaxError

Comment: how to make not to round the integer i want to keep decimals ?

Comment: I think you need then to create a custom template tag without round.

Answer (score 0):

{{d|mul:100}} should do the multiplication for you.
More detail at this link: https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30840504)